# encryption keys in frontend

Tags: reactjs, security, encryption

So I have a dashboard but it's only supposed to be used for users with the right roles. Note this role is not defined in the database somewhere. I have a separate login system with username/password combined with Google authenticator.

When the user is logged in in the session I store a key value pair which is encrypted to check if the user is an "admin".

Now some of these API calls the dashboard makes are only supposed for the dashboard so it has some extra security it takes a body with a key that gets validated in the backend.

All these keys are stored in plain text in the frontend, is this a security liability or are end users not able to access the reactjs frontend code?

Comment: Yes, that's a security liability. Anything in the front-end is accessible to a determined attacker.

Comment: These keys you store in your front end: do they expire? Can your validation scheme in the back end tell if they have aged out? Are they single-use (nonce) keys, where the operation of validating them also expires them? Can your user invalidate them, by logging out or some such thing? If an attacker knows some valid keys, is it possible to guess other valid keys? Please [edit] your question to tell us more.

Comment: Your keys sound more like tokens. It is possible to have a relatively secure operation with tokens when e.g. combined with TLS. Fleshing out a complete security strategy is however off topic, and questions about such security are better asked at [security.se], but please first read their tour and search for dupes if you do.

Comment: @O.Jones No these don't expire once they are known they could be able to use them.